# iOS Multitasking App Launch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I developed an app for IPhone and it's posted to itunes for approval. Now when I test the app I found out a strange behavior which I think should be rectified. When I launch app first time, the app launched and when I press home button it closes but when I tap the app icon to open it again it opens where it was last closed.

How can I change the view to first view of the app when it's launched after closing by Home screen button?

Comment: Most people consider that a feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want your app to run in the background you need to set the "Application does not run in background" key in the info.plist file.  This means that your app will completely restart every time your user returns to it.  Take time to decide if this really is the best move for your app.  Allowing users to return to where they left off or remembering information about the last session can be a big plus.

If you do not set the info.plist value like I mention above you can manage the way your app behaves by using the: `applicationWillEnterForeground:` in `UIApplicationDelegate` or you could observe UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotifications.  Read up on all the available notifications and methods available for this in the UIApplication Delegate documentation.